# Imput/Output Devices Not Found After Plugging In Headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16, so I update&upgrade it. I then go on youtube to test out the speakers. The built in speakers in my laptop work fine, until I plug in my headphones. After I do that, the headphones, microphone, and the built in headphone/mic disappear from System Settings > Sound > and completely disappear from alsamixer (so I can't unmute them). I looked around for how to fix the issue, and to no prevail, I reinstalled my system again. I tried the same thing, and had the exact same issue.

Are there any fixes for this issue, or do you have any suggestions for me? Any help is welcome :)

Comment: can you run this command and update the question with it's output `aplay -l`

Comment: The output of `dmesg -w` when you plug your headphones would also be useful.

Comment: after running aplay -l I got the following:
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Here's the output of dmesg -w:
https://0bin.net/paste/Is-7CYp1mhUE183q#810eP-3iqw1bm9kbgajEPSrraem9IKsoyNwZVotokud